# Moving Windows 7 profile to new user

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

I have a laptop which I've been using as part of a corporate network with an AD login (and associated local profile).  The laptop is loaded with Windows 7 Ultimate.   I need to remove the laptop from this domain and, to start this process, I have already configured a local user on the box for me to use moving forward (granting this user the same local admin rights as the AD user).  I'd like to migrate all the files, settings, etc from the local AD profile to the new non-AD profile.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Anything built into Win 7?  As far as basic files I can probably just manually copy all the documents, pictures, music, desktop, favorites, etc...  But is there a more streamlined way to move profile information?

-Kevin

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to use Windows Easy Transfer, Whilst it is designed to move from computer to computer, if you do it on the same, it should work just the same!... Just uncheck everything other than your username.

(Look under Accessories > System Tools for this).

After this, you may want to take a look at the real way it is meant to be done (However this sometimes gives me problems). Go to Control Panel > System Settings (Shortcut: <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>) and click `Advanced System Settings`, next click `Settings` under the `User Profiles` section.

Find the user and click `Copy To` and/or `Change Type`... You will not be able to do this on the user you are logged in as. I use this tool mainly to change a user to a roaming user, I am not sure exactly if it can be used to do exactly what you want, but it may be worth a try.